# attach JQuery, Ajax Result with more then one div

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want attach the ajax response with more then one div at a time...is this possible?

i want to like given below...but in this function, the ajax response only attached in '#res' div and not attache with '.qty' div...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.qty').on('change', function() {
  var qty_val=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url:"addcart.php",
      data:{ qty: qty_val },

      success:function(result){

      $("#res").html(result);
      $(".qty").html(result);

      }})
});
});
```

Comment: can you share the html for `qty` element

Comment: <input type="number" name="qty" id="'.$ppid.'" class="qty" value="" style="width:50px" min="1">

Comment: this is my qty part...$ppid is dynamic value arun

Comment: since it is an input element, you need to use `.val()`

Comment: yes this work arun...but another problem is my 'qty' part is inside of loop...so i want to pass individual qty value...but if i change one qty part, all 'qty' part is changing automatically...could u understand what i mean?

Comment: see the update in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like `qty` is an input element as it is firing change event, try

```
$(".qty").val(result);
```

Update:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.qty').on('change', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            qty_val = $this.val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "addcart.php",
            data: {
                qty: qty_val
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#res").html(result);
                $this.val(result);

            }
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is an on change on the css class qty.
However within the ajax request you also change the qty class. So you're basically create a loop this way.

Try to change the on change to on click and click on the class.
See if it does work now, if it does, you've proven my point above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.qty').on('click', function() {
        var qty_val=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:"addcart.php",
            data:{ qty: qty_val },

            success:function(result){

                $("#res").html(result);
                $(".qty").html(result);

            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry my qty class actually not a div..this is given like this...<input type="number" name="qty" id="'.$ppid.'" class="qty" value="" style="width:50px" min="1">

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Arun...Look [at this](http://jsfiddle.net/TGjF8/) js fiddle example..its a little simpler than your code, but basically it does the same thing...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#clickme').on('click', function()
   {
      $('.qty').val(8);
   });
});
```